# How to get an iPhone address book contact's emails as NSStrings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I know that there can be multiple values for an email, but I'm not sure how to browse through them.

I can get a person correctly.

```
ABRecordRef person = // getting a person;
NSString* emails = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
```

... what's next? If I try to print the `emails` variable I get:

```
Emails: <NSCFType: 0x4018d40>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because emails should not be a string, but an array.  People can have many emails!

```
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
CFStringRef email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, <INDEX>);
NSLog( (NSString *) email);
```

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABMultiValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ABMultiValue) are some docs on things you can do with MultiValueLists

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can get the size of the "emails" array so I can browse it?

Comment: i added a link to the docs where you will find the 'count' method

Comment: for the count I ended up using this: CFIndex count = ABMultiValueGetCount(emails);

Answer (score 4):

The type of this entry is an `ABMultiValue` (specifically, the type of this field is a `kABMultiStringProperty`). See ["Using Multivalue Lists"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AccessingData.html) for how to read these. See the [Address Book Objective-C Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Miscellaneous/AddressBook_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003952-CH3g-SW10) for what each property returns.

Also, remember that AB functions are subject to the [Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148). You are responsible for releasing objects you get from a function with the word "Copy" in it.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9 the ABFramework has been deprecated for the new **Contacts Framework**:

I show you an example to log every email address of a CNContact:

```
CNContact * yourContact = //...

for (CNLabeledValue* emailLabeledValue in yourContact.emailAddresses){
    NSLog(@"%@",[emailLabeledValue value]);
}
```