# Efficient way to retrieve contacts by email and phone number in ios

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I am building an autocomplete feature for an ios application. After getting all the contacts in  CFArrayRef. What would be the most efficient way to retrieve the contacts by email and phone number given a search string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched on SO? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645567/how-to-get-an-iphone-address-book-contacts-emails-as-nsstrings)? Or looked on Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)?

After getting all contacts you can compare the strings with `compare:` or `rangeOfString:`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, just as the user decided to enter something where I might need this, I would essentially create an NSArray of dictionaries for each contact (coverting the address objects into full fledged Cocoa objects).

Then as the user types, you can use nested "enumerate" block methods provided by both NSArray and NSDictionary to rapidly find the appropriate entry.

Comment: could you provide  some code on how exactly to search once you  have the array of people objects.